# Linux script for file change email notification ( not inotify or any other utility)

Tags: scripting

I'm looking for linux script (not inotify tool or any other utilities ) which notifies me via email whenever file contents are changed. I have managed sample script via google, but i have to run it manually and it is not triggering any emails

```
[[ -z `find /path/to/file -mmin -60` ]]

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo -e " /path/to/file nothing has changed"
else
  mail -s "/path/to/file has been changed" mailid
fi
```

Comment: `-mmin -60` is negative sixty minutes ago.  Or, put another way, sixty minutes into the future.

Comment: No need for a script - just use this cron job! `* * * * * find /path/to/file -mmin -1 -exec mail -s 'Subject here' email@example.com <<< 'Message here' \;`

Comment: @DopeGhoti that's not right. `-60` means _less than 60 minutes ago_. There's no way with `find` to reference times in the future except possibly with variations of `-newermt`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a script that does what you want it to do, add the script to your cron table (or `crontab`), and the job will run at whatever frequency you like.  So:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [[ -z $(find /path/to/file -mmin 60) ]]; then
    # The file was changed, so:
    echo -e "The hash is:\n$(md5sum /path/to/file)" | mail -s "/file has changed on $(hostname -s) username@example.com"
else
    # If this is in the crontab, remove this else stanza; cron
    # jobs should not write to standard output, lest that output
    # be sent to the local mailer daemon to drop it into the owner's
    # mailbox.
    echo "No changes to /path/to/file detected."
fi
```

Comment: A better approach might be the time since the last successful run; I had the misfortune of having to support a workflow that assumed the last job ran an hour prior once...

Comment: Oh, been there; done that.  I ended up writing this probably-too-convoluted job that dropped state files in `/var/run` which subsequent instances of the job would inspect.

Answer (score 0):

> but i have to run it manually

What really matters is how soon you need the email notification. If it doesn't have to be very quick then a cron job would suffice. Either capture the file modification time elsewhere and compare this value or use 'find' with -mtime / -mmin. Alternatively touch a flag file. If the target file is newer than the flag file, send the email then refresh the timestamp on the flag file.

If you want a (near) immediate notification, then have a look at [incron](https://linux.die.net/man/1/incrontab)

> and it is not triggering any emails

...is improbable. Check your logs. Why emails don't get delivered is asked very frequently here.